# Determine camera change event was programatic

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I want to determine whether the camera changed event was initiated from the user or not. (i have to make different actions based on that). So if the user pans a camera with the finger, i have to close sg, but if i moved the camera with the API, i do not.

Currently i cannot decide it was a user event or not, in my `OnCameraChangeListener`, because the `onCameraChange(CameraPosition var1)` method does not provide any kind of information about that.

I also tried to save the last marker position which i animated onto programmatically, and check that in the listener method:

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogelMap.onCameraChangeListener {
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
            if (!cameraPosition.target.equals(lastClickedMarker)) {
                // this is a user event
            }
}
```

I set the `lastClickedMarker` with the `OnMarkerClickListener`. I found out i cannot rely on this, because the `cameraPosition` and `lastClickedMarker` coordinates will always differ a little, even if really animate to that marker programmatically with `animateCamera()`.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a boolean before you change the camera programatically, and check if it is set (and unset) in the `onCameraChange` method.

Something like this:

```
// Moving programmatically
cameraMovedProgrammatically = true;
map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

And checking it:

```
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
    if (cameraMovedProgrammatically) {
        // this is not a user event
        cameraMovedProgrammatically = false;
    } else {
        // this is a user event
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be careful with cameraUpdates, that do not really change the position. In that case onCameraChange will not be called and the next manual move will look like a programmatically started move. I am also not sure what happens if an animated programmatic move is intercepted by a manual move (while animation is still running). I don't think onCameraChange will then be called twice.

Comment: I would reset the flag cameraMovedProgrammatically in addition when a touchEvent is detected, to avoid the problems mentioned in my previous comment. (It was too late to edit the comment)